# Can't force EF to use plural name for table

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a `Subject` class and a `Course` class. They are in a many-to-many relationship so I also have a `CourseSubject` class with navigation properties and id properties to the other two classes. I can now read subjects and courses from the database but whenever I try to save eg. an updated `Subject` instance, I get a MySqlException that it failed to save to the `CourseSubject` table... even though the table name is `CourseSubjects` (plural)!

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Descrip { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Course> ParentCourses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Course
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Descrip { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public partial class CourseSubject
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public string SubjectId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public string? PrevSubjectInCourseId { get; set; }
    public string? NextSubjectInCourseId { get; set; }
    public string? ReasonToBeInCourse { get; set; }
}
```

My OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CourseId, e.SubjectId })
        .HasName("PRIMARY")
        .HasAnnotation("MySql:IndexPrefixLength", new[] { 0, 0 });
});

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>().ToTable("CourseSubjects", "dbo");

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>()
    .HasOne(cs => cs.Subject);

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>()
    .HasOne(cs => cs.Course);
```

The exception:
[image: Exception]

From the generated SQL query I can see it makes the Subject and the Course plural, instead of the CourseSubject:
[image]

I've tried using the `[Table("CourseSubjects")]` attribute on the CourseSubject class. I've tried adding the explicit table name for the model builder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>().ToTable("CourseSubjects", "dbo");
```

Nothing helps. The other tables are also plural and they work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the generated SQL. Try updating to the lastest EF Core 6 release, or consider updating your packages to EF Core 7 which targets .NET 6 - I'm using it myself in that way too (although not on MySQL), needed no code changes, runs great and offers new & improved features and better performance.

Comment: I've updated all EF-related packages. Still the same error.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my post. I can see in the generated SQL it makes the Subject and the Course plural, instead of the CourseSubject.

Comment: Did you associate `CourseSubject` as join entity for MTM skip navigations? e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(e => e.Subjects).WithMany(e => e.ParentCourses).UsingEntity<CourseSubject>(...)`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, the code I posted is all I have. Can you write the whole line for this setup? I'll be happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Exception detail to check,
I think it's not related to your table name unless there is a difference between your table name and your entity name, but I think they have the same name, so share more details about the problem,
try this:

```
    public partial class Subject
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Descrip { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<CourseSubject> ParentCourses { get;  }= new()
}

public partial class Course
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Descrip { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<CourseSubject> Subjects { get;  } = new()
}

public partial class CourseSubject
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Course Course { get; }
    public string SubjectId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; }
    public string? PrevSubjectInCourseId { get; set; }
    public string? NextSubjectInCourseId { get; set; }
    public string? ReasonToBeInCourse { get; set; }
}
```

and be sure your table exists in your db,

Edited:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>().ToTable("CourseSubject", "dbo");
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>()
        .HasOne(cs => cs.Subject).WithMany(c=>c.ParentCourses)
.HasForeignKey(cs=>cs.SubjectId).HasConstraintName(FK_CourseSubject_SubjectId);;
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseSubject>()
        .HasOne(cs => cs.Course).WithMany(c=>c.Subjects)
.HasForeignKey(cs=>cs.CourseId).HasConstraintName(FK_CourseSubject_CourseId);
```

Comment: Added the exception. But it doesn't say much.

Comment: so, does your table exist in Db???
the exception says that the table does not exist!!!
did you update your database after adding the entity??

Comment: oh buddy, your collections must be from "CourseSubject" type

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I can read the table. I just can't write to it for some reason.

Comment: Using CourseSubject for collections throws a DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

Comment: @Val  check the edited version

Comment: This line shows an error in VS `.HasOne(cs => cs.Subject).WithMany(c => c.ParentCourses)` under `c.ParentCourses`. Says it cannot implicitly convert Course to CourseSubject (the `Subject` cotains Courses of type `Course` right now as that's how all tutorials do it).

Comment: Dude, I said change the type of Course to CourseSubject , then add this line,
When you want to break ManyToMany relation to OneToMany you can have middle table on both sides and cannot use each side for another

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Many-to-many with class for join entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-class-for-join-entity), hence it needs some additional fluent configuration to associate the join entity with the skip navigations, map its navigations, FKs, table and columns names etc. All this with some of the [`UsingEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.collectioncollectionbuilder-2.usingentity?view=efcore-7.0) overloads.

For instance:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Subjects)
    .WithMany(e => e.ParentCourses)
    .UsingEntity<CourseSubject>(
        configureRight: je => je.HasOne(e => e.Subject).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.SubjectId),
        configureLeft: je => je.HasOne(e => e.Course).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.CourseId),
        configureJoinEntityType: je =>
        {
            je.ToTable("CourseSubjects");
            je.HasKey(e => new { e.CourseId, e.SubjectId });
        }
    );
```

Comment: I've added this and now I get `MySqlException: Duplicate entry 'd66e4e74-5304-407e-8ccf-8cc2fa444c0e-0daf2fc1-111f-45e3-8750-...' for key 'PRIMARY'` - probably because one of the CourseSubject relations is already there (and I wanted to add a new one).

Comment: Also, is there some tutorial on how to understand and exercise configuring entities for EF? I can't find anything reasonable. Even courses on Udemy explain this very briefly.

Comment: (1) That's normal, even in your original configuration the pair `(CourseId, SubjectId)` is a PK, i.e. the combination must be unique (2) I'm afraid I cannot help with links. All my EF Core knowledge is from official docs, source code and experiments.

Comment: So I cannot just add new courses to a subject and then save it, I need to first check in db which courses it has, remove them from the list to keep only the new ones, and then save? That's how EF is supposed to work?

Comment: @Val You know the rules, single question per post please. Even if I wish to answer "additional" questions, comments area is quite limited for such things. Not to count that working with disconnected entities is a whole area in docs with no universal solution for all usage scenarios.